# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature is available only when the element type is implementing RealmModel

Tags: java, realm, realm-list

In my app, I'm saving an **Arraylist** to realmlist and that list is being saved to realm database so now at runtime *when I try to fetch result with some search query it gives me* `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature is available only when the element type is implementing RealmModel.`

I can't seem to understand what is wrong here. Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my realm class:

```
public class Vendordb extends RealmObject {
    public RealmList<String> getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    public void setVendor(RealmList<String> vendor) {
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }
    RealmList<String> vendor = new RealmList<>();
}
```

This is the code for create realmlist:

```
final List<String> vendors = macvendorDatabaseAccess.getvendors();
            final RealmList<String> vend = new RealmList<>();
            vend.addAll( vendors );
            macvendorDatabaseAccess.close();
                realm.executeTransaction( new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        Vendordb vendordb = realm.createObject( Vendordb.class );
                        vendordb.setVendor(vend);
                    }
                } );
```

//At this piece of code i'm getting error:

```
 Vendordb vendordb = realm.where(Vendordb.class).findFirst();
                RealmList<String> vendor = vendordb.getVendor();
                RealmResults<String> filteredMembers = vendor.where().equalTo("mac", identifier).findAll();
               if (!filteredMembers.isEmpty()) {
                   holder.vendor.setText( filteredMembers.get( 0 ).toString() );
               }
```

Comment: Because it's a `RealmList<String` and not a `RealmList<some Realm model`˙

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `setVendor`, your use of an unmanaged `RealmList` outside of an object, and using a query on a non-Realm object (in this case a primitive String).

In `setVendor`, you cannot reassign the value of the list at this time; the list already exists, so you have to modify its contents.

`RealmList` should only be used within an object where it is managed. You shouldn't try and use them outside of the object.

Although it's admirable to try and encapsulate the `RealmList` in the object and provide accessors, it doesn't actually help here; you'll notice the Realm examples always use public members. You can make them private if you wish, but your accessors should then hide the implementation and dependency on Realm and provide you with the necessary operations your application layer needs.

So, delete the `getVendor` and `setVendor` methods from your model.

Next, add methods to do your dirty work. E.g.

```
public class Vendordb extends RealmObject {

  RealmList<String> vendor = new RealmList<>();

  public void addVendors(List<String> vendors)
  {
    this.vendor.addAll(vendors);
  }
}
```

Your 'create' section then becomes:

```
final List<String> vendors = macvendorDatabaseAccess.getvendors();
macvendorDatabaseAccess.close();

realm.executeTransaction( new Realm.Transaction() {
  @Override
  public void execute(Realm realm) {
    Vendordb vendordb = realm.createObject( Vendordb.class );
    vendordb.addVendors(vendors);
  }
} );
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do in the final 'search' part. You have a list of strings but are performing a 'where' on a primitive type - this is probably what is generating your runtime error. Think about what you want to pull out of the list of strings, and then add a similar method to find it for you (maybe just a call to `contains`).